# How to programmatically set table name in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created the following simple PL/SQL stored procedure example to ask a specific question. This procedure inserts an employee name and id number into a table called `employees_???`. The ??? is explained below.

```
PROCEDURE hire_employee (emp_id IN INTEGER, name IN VARCHAR2, country IN VARCHAR2) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employees_??? VALUES (emp_id, name, 1000);
END hire_employee;
```

What I need is to set the table name based on the IN variable `country`. For example,

If country = 'usa', I want the INSERT line to read:

```
INSERT INTO employees_usa VALUES (emp_id, name, 1000);
```

If country = 'germany', I want the INSERT line to read:

```
INSERT INTO employees_germany VALUES (emp_id, name, 1000);
```

If country = 'france', I want the INSERT line to read:

```
INSERT INTO employees_france VALUES (emp_id, name, 1000);
```

etc...

Is there a way to do this in PL/SQL by substituting something in place of `employee_???` so only one line of code for INSERT is used? Or is using a `case` or `if/then/else` statement the best way?

Comment: Your DB model is completely broken. You should only have a single table `employee` with a column named `country`. Instead of fighting the problems that you get with this wrong model you should immediately re-design it.

Comment: Yes, I agree -- it's just an example created to figure out how to get the IN parameter onto a variable name in pl/sql.

Comment: Then it's a **very** bad example.

Comment: Please provide an example that truly describes what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: OK, I've created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959799/pl-sql-re-write-select-statement-using-in-parameter-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, you have to use [`execute immediate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) and create your statement dynamically.

```
create or replace procedure hire_employee (
        emp_id IN INTEGER
      , name IN VARCHAR2
      , country IN VARCHAR2 ) is

   -- maximum length of an object name in Oracle is 30
   l_table_name varchar2(30) := 'employees_' || country;

begin
    execute immediate 'insert into ' || l_table_name
                       || ' values (:1, :2, 1000)'
      using emp_id, name;
end hire_employee;
```

However, this is a massively over-complicated way of storing the data. If you want to select *all* data you have to union large numbers of tables.

It would be far better to normalise the database properly and add country to an `employees` table.

Something like the following:

```
create table employees (
    emp_id number(16)
  , country varchar2(3) -- ISO codes
  , name varchar2(4000) -- maximum who knows what name people might have
  , < other_columns >
  , constraint pk_employees primary key ( emp_id )
    );
```

Your procedure then becomes a very simple insert statement:

```
create or replace procedure hire_employee (
       emp_id in integer
     , name in varchar2
     , country in varchar2 ) is

    insert into employees
    values ( emp_id, country, name, 1000 );

end hire_employee;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic SQL and the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE construct. In this, you construct the query as a string and then execute it. A good example is at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm