# PL/SQL: re-write SELECT statement using IN parameter in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose I have an Oracle 11.2 database containing the following table:

```
TABLE: SURVEY

PARAMETER    MALE   FEMALE 
--------------------------
SAMPLE_SIZE  102       95
AVG_WEIGHT   170      120
AVG_HEIGHT   5.9      5.4
```

Here's an example minimal PL/SQL stored procedure that selects the average weight of males and places it (e.g. 170) into variable `v_stat`.

```
PROCEDURE get_stat (gender IN VARCHAR2) 
AS
    v_stat number;
BEGIN
    SELECT male INTO v_stat FROM survey WHERE parameter = 'avg_weight';
END get_stat;
```

Notice the IN parameter `gender` doesn't do anything here. What I want is to pass in variable `gender`, which may equal either 'male' or 'female', and use `gender` somehow in the SELECT statement (instead of 'male'). The goal is to pass in `gender` as a variable that may be used to return, for example, the average weight of, either male or female, as defined by `gender`.

I know I can probably use an IF/THEN/ELSE statement with two separate SELECT statements, but I wondered if there was an elegant way to use just one SELECT statement by changing 'male' in the above SELECT statement to something else?

Note that this is a re-do of my previous question here

[How to programmatically set table name in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957984/how-to-programmatically-set-table-name-in-pl-sql)

that was (rightly) criticized for not being a realistic question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to use the same dynamic SQL approach that was suggested in your other question

```
PROCEDURE get_stat (gender IN VARCHAR2) 
AS
    v_sql   varchar2(1000);
    v_param varchar2(100) := 'AVG_WEIGHT';
    v_stat  number;
BEGIN
    v_sql := 'SELECT ' || gender || ' FROM survey WHERE parameter = :1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
                 INTO v_stat
                USING v_param;
END get_stat;
```

But you'd have the same general objections that were raised in your earlier question-- the data model is fundamentally flawed.  You would be much better served having a separate row for `MALE` and `FEMALE` survey results rather than having separate columns for `male` and `female` results.

Comment: Thanks Justin, why is it better to have separate rows than columns? Is this a general rule of thumb that sometimes does not apply, or is it safe to say it is ALWAYS better to have additional rows if one can eliminate columns?  The data for male and female will always be present.

Comment: @ggkmath - It's essentially always best to at least start with a properly normalized data model.  And a properly normalized data model would have a table with columns like `parameter`, 'gender`, and `result` rather than `parameter`, `male`, and `female`.  In general, if you find yourself needing to pick a different table or a different column at runtime, your data model is not properly normalized.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to compose the SELECT statement as string and then use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130) on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have to see how to transform your example, but I know that in SQL Server you can perform dynamic SQL. And, [it appears that you can do this in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm), also.

It would go something like this (I am only going by [examples here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm#26799) as Oracle is not my normal langauge)

```
avg_weight_str := avg_weight;
stmt_str := 'SELECT :gender INTO v_stat FROM survey WHERE parameter = :avg_weight_str';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_str;
```

The problem with dynamic SQL is that it is not as performant. While not elegant, if you only have a two way if, then I would go with the if block so that the code can be more performant.